# How to use managedQuery in the service Android?

Tags: android, browser-history, android-cursor

I have this method but it works only in an activity

```
public Cursor getXX() {
        Cursor mCur = thius.managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, 
                             null, null, null);
}

public void getBrowserHist()  {
    Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, 
                             null, null, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            Log.v("titleIdx", mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_TITLE_INDEX));
            Log.v("urlIdx", mCur.getString(Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION_URL_INDEX));
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use the words "ManagedQuery" in android Service?

How can I create a method to return the cursor to the browser history android system?

Answer (score 9):

`managedQuery()` has been deprecated for over two years and is only relevant for `Activity`.

Your `Service` can call `getContentResolver()`, and call `query()` on it, to query your desired `ContentProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

managedQuery() has been deprecated Use getContentResolver() insted

**Use:** 
Cursor mCur = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

**insted Of:** 
Cursor mCur = managedQuery(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, null);

**its worked with Service**